vm in azure ml studio can't be reached via public ip
I'm fiddling around with azure machine learning studio. I have created an ai generation project, where I have a linux VM with public ip address. This vm hosts something which is locally accessible.
I also have a resource group with inbound rule inside of it, which should allow all incoming traffic on a specific port/port range(I have tried different ranges. The vm in MLS has a port of 50000, I have also tried it). But it does nothing.
If you have any ideas what's wrong or have experienced such an issue I would like to hear you out.


vm in azure ml studio can't be reached via public ip

If you are unable to connect to the Azure VM from ML Studio, make sure to check the steps below

Check the local firewall status using the command below

               sudo ufw status


Note: If the firewall is not required, kindly disable it using the command below.

sudo ufw Disable

If the firewall is active, allow port 5000 through the firewall. If it is not active, there is no need to allow any ports
sudo ufw allow 5000

Result:


Make sure that the application is running on port 5000 on your VM. If port 5000 is not active on your VM, it will not be possible to connect from outside via that port.



Make sure to test the connection to your VM using its public IP address from your local machine.

    curl http://<Your_VM_Public_IP>:5000


Check the NSG rules to ensure that the inbound rule allows port 5000 and also verify that the outbound rules do not block port 5000.



Finally, when I tried to access the VM using the public IP from the ML notebook, I was able to connect to the VM successfully.


Refer: Can't access an app on Azure VM via Public IP by TP

Firewall was disabled, but still I couldn't connect. I have enabled it, added specific ports to allow-list but still nothing changed.

Are there any services running on port 5000 on your VM? For testing, check with port 22.

Install NGINX by following the link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04 and try to connect VM from ML studio with port 80 for testing.

Port 50000 is a port for vm itself i suppose, when I press connect I see a popup with ssh information and port number is specified in there. Vm itself should be hosting application which is on port 8188

Do you mean application is running on VM with port 50000 or Port 8188?

For simple testing, first run a Python app on port 50000 using the following sudo apt install python3 -y and Start the Python HTTP server on port 50000 python3 -m http.server 50000 Next, open another terminal and run the following command to check if the app is running on port 50000 (do not close the existing terminal): sudo netstat -tulnp | grep :50000

I just tested with port 50000, and the app is running on port 50000 in my VM. Additionally, ML also connected using the same port; here is the result

I hope this helps to resolve your problem.
